# how to rectify the error in google places api in android

Tags: android, google-maps, autocompletetextview

Hi I am using google maps with searchbox to show places in `AutoCompleteTextView` like `google maps`. I am using a single api key by enabling `google maps` android api,`google maps places` api google maps webservice api. I want maps and autocomplete to work in release mode. I am getting error like this:

> Unable to fetch autocomplete results from the api        com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.model.PlacesApiException: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 2405:205:810a:751f:6c8e:2381:c79a:eee4, with empty referer.

My manifest code is

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

My **autocompletetextview**

```
<com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.PlacesAutocompleteTextView
              android:id="@+id/places_autocomplete"
              android:hint="drop address"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@android:color/white"
              android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_24dp"
              android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_location_black_48dp"
              android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_24dp"
              android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add_location_black_48dp"
              android:elevation="10dp"
              android:isScrollContainer="true"
              android:ellipsize="end"
              android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
              android:singleLine="true"
              app:pacv_historyFile="@string/pacv_default_history_file_name
              app:pacv_googleMapsApiKey="@string/google_maps_key"
              android:layout_below="@+id/ed_place_autocomplete"
              android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imagebutton_searchView"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

I generate key for debug and release with sha1 fingerprint and package name and stored it in **strings\google_api_xml** file under values. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check  that your Manifest file contains all the required **permissions** and **google play services version** defined.

For **google maps v2** you need **android key** and for **google places api** you need a **server key**.

Make sure you have enabled API.